# How to use functions in functional component React

Tags: reactjs

I have this code which uses a class based component:

```
export default class Sidebar extends Component {
  renderHello() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        {this.renderHello()}
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I call `renderHello` in the `render()` method to create an `h1`. How could I do this with a class based component:

```
function Sidebar() {

  {/* Should I write the function here?? */}

  return (
    <div>
      {/* How to call a function here?? */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Usage is the same, just without `this`, i.e. `function renderHello() {...` and `{renderHello()}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it .

```
function Sidebar() {


  const renderHello = () => <h1>Hello</h1>

  return (
    <div>
      {renderHello()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between `const` and `function` for the `renderHello`?

Comment: What we have done here is used an arrow function assigned it to renderHello.

Comment: So In a sense renderHello is still a function

Comment: I see, but what is the difference between writing `const renderHello = () => {}` and `function renderHello() {}`? Is it just a syntax difference?

Comment: as far as i know there is no difference in this case

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Appreciate all the help!!